# Joomla PHP include call variables in article from custom PHP

Tags: php, variables, joomla, article

I have install DirectPHP and it works fine, I can actually print out the current time with PHP, so I know it works.

My problem lies in using a custom PHP to call out variables and print out in all my articles.

**First:** My custom php inside `/media/custom.php`

```
<?php
// Rental Prices Equipment
$miniraeClassic_d = "$35.00";
$miniraeClassic_m = "$120.00";
$miniraeClassic_y = "$400.00";

$message = "Hello World";
?>
```

**Second:** Here is where I included the PHP file I want to retrieve information from. This was included in the index.php of my template.

```
// Preparing template parameters
JSNTplTemplateHelper::prepare();

// Get template utilities
$jsnutils = JSNTplUtils::getInstance();
?>
<?php
include '/media/custom.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- <?php echo $this->template . ' ' . JSNTplHelper::getTemplateVersion($this->template); ?> -->
<html lang="<?php echo $this->language ?>" dir="<?php echo $this->direction; ?>">
<head>
```

**Third:** In my article I added two codes, one trying to retrieve `$message` from my `custom.php`, and another to test if PHP actually works in my article (which prints out the time).

```
<?php
echo $message;
?>

Now is: <?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');?>
```

[image]

**Fourth:** here is the result, in my article, it does not print out $message, but it does print out the date and time.

```
It did not print out $message
in my article, the only thing it printed out was

Now is: 2014-05-28 22:21:50
```

[image]

I want to call out multiple variable around my article i.e.

```
<table border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td width="32%" align="center" class="table-title"><b>Daily</b></td>
<td width="34%" align="center" class="table-title"><b>Weekly</b></td>
<td width="34%" align="center" class="table-title"><b>Monthly</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" class="table-content"><?= $dayrental?></td>
<td align="center" class="table-content"><?= $weekrental?></td>
<td align="center" class="table-content"><?= $monthrental?></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following to import your custom php file:

```
<?php
    include(JUri::root() . 'templates/' . $this->template . '/media/custom.php');
?>
```

`JUri::root()` defined the root of your Joomla installation which you have not defined in your code.

Comment: i tried that right now, changed it to <?php
    include(JUri::root() . 'templates/' . $this->template . '/custom.php');
?> and added the custom php where my template index.php resides and still no "hello world" message in my article.

Comment: however, i added to my custom php `code`<?php
// Rental Prices Equipment
$miniraeClassic_d = "$35.00";
$miniraeClassic_m = "$120.00";
$miniraeClassic_y = "$400.00";

$message = "Hello World";
echo "<font color"#000000">MY MY MY</font>";`code` and i checked my article source code and found `code`<font color<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- jsn_epic_free 6.0.3 -->
<html lang="en-gb" dir="ltr">
<head>`code`